# how to find the DISTANCE of a point in higher dimension(say 19) to its kth(say 20th) nearest neighbor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Is there any function or library in python which can help me find the DISTANCE between a point (having 19 features) and its 20th nearest neighbor?

I have tried **Euclidean distance** but as i have nearly 600 000 records (points) so I am encountering **MemoryError**. Is there a more efficient and pythonic way of finding the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is with `sklearn.neighbors.KNearestNeighbor`.

This prepares a dataset similar to yours (600000 samples with 19 features) and fits a knn model:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

N = 600000
N_ATTR = 19

samples = np.random.normal(size=(N, N_ATTR))
y = np.ones(N,)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=20)
knn.fit(samples, y)
```

Here we use a knn with up to 20 neighbors. The distance between `query`and the all nearest neighbors can be obtained by calling the `kneighbors`function:

```
query = np.random.normal(size=(1, N_ATTR))
distances = knn.kneighbors(query)[0]
```

and for the one corresponding to the 20th neighbor:

```
distance_to_20th = distances[0,-1]
```

`KNearestNeighbor`uses the Euclidean distance by default.

Comment: The data-set I am having currently doesn't have any y. i.e. no output labels(its a clustering problem). So in that scenario, how to use this solution???

Comment: The `k_neighbors` function does not use the labels, but strictly speaking, to  use the class `KNeighborsClassifier` you need to pass a vector of y's. You can artificially create such a vector as in the example (with `np.ones`)